# How to layout a FormLayout in vaadin 7 like a Form in vaadin 6?

Tags: layout, vaadin

I'm trying to migrate an application from vaadin 6.8 to vaadin 7. Since the Form class is deprecated in vaadin 7 i'm trying to build my forms with FieldGroup and present them with FormLayout. Building is not a problem, but the layout doesn't work so smoothly. Right now i have two Problems.

1. How do I display the form description on top over the full width of the form? I'd like to have it exactly the same width and neither wider nor only in the second column.
2. How do I add the buttons (OK and cancel) so they are next to each other and not only in the second column? Like the footer in the old Form class.

Is this possible with FormLayout or do I have use another Layout?

Thanks 
Raffael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: I've literally only started investigating V7 in the last week, so exercise caution with my response...*

Both of these problems stem from the fact that FormLayout never provided a header and a footer - the Form class did.

I would suggest creating your own equivalent of Form that has a header layout, a FormLayout and a footer layout e.g. (Not tried to use, might need to use a GridLayout instead of VerticalLayout for mainLaout)

```
public class FormComponent extends CustomComponent {
  private Layout mainLayout;

  protected Layout header;
  protected Layout central;
  protected Layout footer;

  public FormComponent() {
    init(new HorizontalLayout(), new FormLayout(), new HorizontalLayout());
  }

  protected void init(Layout header, Layout central, Layout footer) {
    this.footer = footer;
    this.header = header;
    this.central = central;

    mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    mainLayout.addComponent(header);
    mainLayout.addComponent(central);
    mainLayout.addComponent(footer);

    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
    setSizeUndefined();
  }

  public Layout getHeader() {
    return header;
  }

  public Layout getCentral() {
    return central;
  }

  public Layout getFooter() {
    return footer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already taught something this way, but hoped for a built-in solution. I'm going to wait some more and will accept your answer if there is really nothing out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Vaadin 7 there's no built-in component equivalent to Vaadin 6 Form component. So you must create your own.
2. Create new HorizontalLayout and add your OK and Cancel button to it. Then add that HorizontalLayout to your FormLayout.